# How do I open a directory in gnome-terminal using context menu?

Tags: pantheon-files, gnome-terminal, context-menu

I recently installed the gnome-terminal and removed pantheon-terminal. Now The 'Open in > Terminal' in context menu is no longer working. How can I use that option to open the current directory in gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function of Terminal itself. Pantheon Terminal makes Files aware that it is available to handle directories through a .desktop file. GNOME Terminal would have to supply a .desktop file that would indicate to Files that it handles directories.

You may be able to work around this by creating your own .desktop file for GNOME Terminal and placing it in `$PREFIX/share/applications` (Where $PREFIX is `/usr` or `/usr/local`). This is the contents of the .desktop file that Pantheon Terminal supplies for this purpose:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
TryExec=pantheon-terminal
Exec=pantheon-terminal -w %u
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=pantheon-terminal
NoDisplay=true
MimeType=inode/directory;
```

Notice specifically the `Exec` line. If GNOME Terminal is able to accept directories as a command line argument, this is where you would modify the .desktop file to have it work with GNOME Terminal instead of Pantheon Terminal.